# Can "make something out of ..." mean what I want to mean here?

Tags: expressions, writing

Life for this sparrow is very hard, but even so, she had a pleasant character. Then an eagle fell in love with her. He explained to her:

> I did not adore you because you could **make an adorable sparrow merely
>   out of discomfort**, distress, and even sorrow. No, you could not. I
>   love you because you had built such an attractive and agreeable
>   character, on such an imperfect and precarious basis. （self-made）

My purpose is to say that adversities themselves did not make the sparrow cute, but the fact that she became a cute on adverse conditions. I doubt that “make… out of” means the same as “build…on the basis of”, and thus that all my words finally means nothing.

Comment: I would use would instead of could. She cannot make a sparrow (e.g. create a sparrow), but would make a sparrow (e.g. be a sparrow)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use this phrase but your particular example is a little hard to understand. A more traditional usage:

> We make soldiers out of sweat, blood and tears.

It does mean "build" but it isn't really paired with "on the basis of"; it would mean "out of these materials."

> We build soldiers out of sweat, blood and tears.
>
> We make houses out of wood.
>
> We build houses out of wood.

This means your third sentence has a similar problem:

> I love you because you had built such an attractive and agreeable character, on such an imperfect and precarious basis.

I recommend:

> I love you because you built such an attractive and agreeable character in spite of such imperfect and precarious circumstances.

The entire example:

> I did not adore you simply because you made an adorable sparrow out of your discomfort, distress, and sorrow. No, you could not. I love you because you built such an attractive and agreeable character in spite of such imperfect and precarious circumstances.

There are a few other minor touch-ups I would perform on the paragraph but this should directly address your specific concern.